Hide element in Jetpack Compose if it does not fit into maximal height?
In Jetpack Compose I want to implement a Card or similar having a header and a body.
The height of the body has a maximal height.
The body shall ever be visible. Except of: When the body content's height exceeds the body height then the body shall be hidden and an expand button in the header appears.
How can do that?
Here is an approximate sketch of the design.
Column {
    // header
    Row {
        Text(text = "title")
        // shall only be visible if body does not into body height
        Button(onClick = {  }) {
            Text("Expand >>")
        }
    }
    // body: shall be hidden if it does not fit into the max height
    Text(modifier = Modifier.heightIn(0.dp, 400.dp), text = "huge text")
}


Presumably, the composition must be re-triggered. But I don't know what's the probable approach. Maybe via onGloballyPositionedModifier()?
Thank you very much.

Learn about the Composable ExpandableCard. Add headerContent and bodyContent as you need it.

I've precised the requirements of the (expandable) card. Sorry, was too imprecise. The point is that the body is ever visible except of when the body content is too high.
What do you meant with ExpandableCard? I found only
https://medium.com/@acceldia/jetpack-compose-creating-expandable-cards-with-content-9ea1eae09efe

You can change how an element is measured and placed with a layout modifier.
private fun Modifier.showWhenHeightFits(onFitsUpdate: (Boolean) -> Unit) =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        // Check if desirable height fits into constraints
        val fits = measurable.maxIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth) <= constraints.maxHeight
        onFitsUpdate(fits)
        if (fits) {
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        } else {
//            layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {}
            // Set Text height to 0 when it doesn't fit
            layout(constraints.maxWidth, 0) {}
        }
    }

And then apply that modifier to the element:
var contentFits by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
// header
Row {
    Text(text = "title")
    if (!contentFits) {
        Button(onClick = { }) {
            Text("Expand >>")
        }
    }
}
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(200.dp)
        .showWhenHeightFits { contentFits = it },
    text = "huge text"
)

